# How does a section of a stack give a sheaf?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, higher-category-theory, descent, algebraic-stacks

At nLab in the article [constant stack](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+stack) and a few other related articles, a pattern is mentioned where a section of a constant sheaf is a locally constant function, a section of a constant stack is a locally constant sheaf, and on up the categorical ladder.

I know that one motivating example of a stack is the functor on a site which assigns to each object the category of sheaves over that object. For this stack, by construction each section is a sheaf. But how do we see that in general? If $F$ is a stack and $c\in F(U)$ I know that $V\mapsto \hom(c|V,c|V)$ is a sheaf, so that’s one way, but I don’t think that is what is meant here.

Comment: Nope, that's it.

Comment: @RyanReich: One reason that I discounted this possibility is that it seemingly produces a sheaf of monoids, instead of just sets, which seems kinda special. Another is that in the example of the stack of sheaves on a site, it does not recover the sheaves which are the objects/sections, but rather only their endomorphism monoids.

Comment: @RyanReich: On the other hand, if you want to get a set out of an object of a category, what other choice is there?

Comment: I think you should go back to the case of a section of a constant sheaf. Yes, a section of a constant sheaf is a locally constant function – think about what its codomain is. Once you do so, it will be clear in what sense a section of a constant stack is a locally constant sheaf.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I replied hastily.  No, what you wrote is not "the" way to do this.  Actually, in trying to explain this, I realized that I take this fact as the *definition* of a constant stack in my mind.

Comment: @ZhenLin: In the case of a constant sheaf $F$ over a topological space $X$ which is the sheafification of a constant presheaf $U\mapsto S$ for some set $S$, so $F(U)=S^{\pi_0(U)}$ (perhaps this requires $X$ be locally connected?), it’s easy to answer: the étale space is trivial bundle $X\times S$ where $S$ is given the discrete topology, so sections over $U$ are just maps $U\to S$.

But I’m not sure how to repeat that logic for the stack. Or even for a sheaf over an arbitrary site. Consider the Grothendieck construction instead of the étale space? Will it be a trivial fibration?

Comment: @RyanReich: My definition of constant stack is the stackification of the functor $U\mapsto C$ for some category $C$. What’s yours?

Comment: @ziggurism the stack whose sections are the locally constant sheaves with coefficients in C :)

Comment: Meaning a sheaf valued in the objects of $C$?

Comment: I think I understand. The problem is that I was expecting to derive a sheaf of sets from a section of a stack with stalk $C$. Instead what I get is a (locally constant) sheaf valued in $C$. If I want to get a sheaf of sets, I should take the constant stack whose stalk is the category of sets.

Answer (score 0):

See the [$n$lab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+constant+sheaf) on locally constant sheaves:

> A locally constant [sheaf](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheaf) $A$ over a [topological space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+space) is a sheaf of [section](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/section)s of a [covering space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/covering+space) of $X$: there is a [cover](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cover) of $X$ by open subsets $\{U_i\}$ such that the [restrictions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inverse+image) $A|_{U_i}$ are [constant sheaves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+sheaf).
>
> More elegantly said: locally constant sheaves are the sections of [constant stack](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+stack)s:
>
> Let $C = \mathrm{Core(FinSet)}\in $[$\mathrm{Grpd}$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/) be the [core](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core) of the [category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/) [$\mathrm{FinSet}$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FinSet) of finite set, let $\mathrm{const}_C : \mathrm{Op}(X)^{op} \to \mathrm{Grpd}$ the [presheaf constant](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+presheaf) on $C$, i.e. the [functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor) on the [opposite category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+category) of the [category of open subsets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+open+subsets) of $X$ that sends everything to (the identity on) $C$. Then the [constant stack](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+stack) on $C$ is the [stackification](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stackification) $\bar{\mathrm{const}_C}: \mathrm{Op}(X)^{op} \to \mathrm{Grpd}$.
>
> Write then $X$ for the space $X$ regarded as a sheaf or trivial [covering space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/covering+space) over itself, i.e. the [terminal object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/terminal+object) $X$ in sheaves and hence in stacks over $X$. Then by definition of stackification morphisms
>
> $$
>   X \to \bar{\mathrm{const}_C}
> $$
>
> are represented by
>
> - an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$;
> - over each $U_i$ a choice $F_i \in C$ of object in $C$, hence a finite set in $C$;
> - over each double overlap $U_{i j} = U_i \cap U_j$ an morphism $g_{i j} : F_i|_{I_{i j}} \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} F_j|_{U_{i j}}$, hence a bijection of finite sets;
> - such that on triple overlaps we have $g_{i k}|_{U_{i j k}}= g_{j k}|_{U_{i j k}}\circ g_{i j}|_{U_{i j k}}$.
>
> Such data clearly is the local data for a [covering space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/covering+space) over $X$ with typical fiber any of the $F_i$.